# Vue / Nuxt.js - Calculate total value of nested JSON values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

Using Nuxt async data, I am fetching a JSON object with a nested array in the following format:

```
"topic_list": {
    "topics": [
      {
        "id": 9148,
        "title": "A",
        "views": 12
      },
      {
        "id": 3228,
        "title": "B",
        "views": 88
      }
      ]
}
```

The data is being loaded asynchronously:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return { topics: 'default', users: '0', views: '0', total: [] }
  },
  asyncData ({ params }, callback) {
    axios.get(`data.json`)
    .then((res) => {
      callback(null, { topics: res.data.topic_list.topics, users: res.data.users,

      })
    })
  }
}
```

I would like to know what would be the best approach to calculating the sum total of all views. I am aware of reduce() and imagine these values need to be pushed into an array - but how to do this with data loaded asynchronously?

Comment: you need computed property for total, where you need to check for `topics` updates

Comment: How can you get all the views array data? `res.data.views` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum the views

```
      callback(null, { topics: res.data.topic_list.topics, users: res.data.users, totalOfViews: 
res.data.topic_list.topics.reduce((sum, currentItem) => (currentItem.views + sum), 0) })
```

This will add the views:

```
res.data.topic_list.topics.reduce((sum, currentItem) => (currentItem.views + sum), 0)
```